# Facebook App Links don't open my app

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

- I have added my URL scheme to my .plist.
- I have manually tested the scheme in Safari and confirmed that it launches my app just fine.
- I have generated a hosted app links link that uses the scheme.
- Nothing except my own URL was entered when creating the hosted app link.

When I tap the link on my phone (with my app installed) it takes me to a page with the text `You have reached an implementation detail`. It's pretty obvious that Facebook didn't even try to use the URL that I had provided when creating this hosted app link.

I should add that I have successfully created other hosted app links moments before that managed to redirect to webpages and to appstore, so there's nothing wrong with mobile Safari.

Where to go from here?

Edit: My app is, of course, in development.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: No, but I'm assuming that since there's no way to check with JS in Safari if a custom scheme can be opened (since ios 9.2), that FB just threw their hands in the air, or started migrating to apple universal links or something. I'm not keeping my hopes up though.

Comment: I've got the same problem... If it was solved please post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue until i updated my app settings in the facebook developer site.

In the image for #1 you enter the prefix (even though it says suffix...) for your url scheme (ex: if you use myapp://testing/here, then enter "myapp" into the field)

make sure #2 is flipped to yes

[Facebook iOS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ2oa.png)

Comment: On what version of iOS did you confirm this working?

Comment: I got it working on version 10.2 on my iphone 5s. It is connected to a dev app on facebook as well. i used this link to check out the meta tags on my site to ensure that it was all correct as well. 

[facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

 my meta tags look like this: 

`<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://test?id=205254"> 
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="1234567890"> 
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="DEVapp"> 
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false">`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but after spending some time on this I realized that the https://fb.me/... links only open from within the Facebook app on the device. They will not (and are not intended) to open from a web browser. After posting the link in a Facebook group I was able to successfully open my app with it.

Comment: I don't recall the details about this but I think Facebook just silently keep changing how they market this feature. From deep linking specific content through an App Store installation, to deeplinking content only if app already installed, to deeplinking only from within Facebooks own apps (because of iOS 9.2). The only thing that's consistent is how confusing it has been to read about.